# ¿Como corregir los "Privilegios de Cuenta de Instalación" para instalar SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

al momento de instalar el SQL Server me sale 1 error sobre: "Privilegios de cuenta de instalación", el resto esta correcto pero gracias a esto no me deja completar la instalación, como puedo solucionarlo para trabajar con C# en Visual Studio 2010.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ese mensaje de error tiene un link que te da más detalles sobre el problema. Cuándo a mi me sucedió, di clic en el link y pude constatar que, en efecto, a pesar de que la cuenta era LocalAdmin en el PC, no tenía un privilegio, en mi caso en particular, el de "Debug Programs".

En su momento, seguí las indicaciones de este buen artículo Web, https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/01/31/interview-question-of-the-week-056-how-to-fix-installation-failure-rule-setup-account-privileges-failed-in-sql-server/, que hacía mención a lo que me sucedía en ese entonces y como resolver. Es un buen paso a paso para resolver el problema.

Tal vez no sea exactamente lo de "Debug Programs", pero seguro esto te ayudará a resolver pronto. Ten presente que cuando pongas el privilegio, como dice ahí, por la funcionalidad de sistema operativo Windows de "Local Security Policy", es mejor reiniciar el PC y reintentar la instalación de nuevo.